Radius relation of four consecutively touching circles $O_7,O_2,O_3,O_6$ with common tangent circles $O_1,O_4$
A construction of four consecutively touching circles $O_7,O_2,O_3,O_6$ that all touches circles $O_1,O_4$:
Triangle $O_1O_2O_3$ has outer Soddy circle $O_4$, so that the circles $O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4$ are mutually tangent.
Let $E,F,G$ be the points of contact of $O_4$ with $O_1,O_2,O_3$.
Circle $H$ is orthogonal to circles $O_1,O_4$ and through $E,F$.
Circle $I$ is orthogonal to circles $O_1,O_4$ and through $E,G$.
Circle $O_7$ is the inversion of circle $O_3$ about circle $H$.
Circle $O_6$ is the inversion of circle $O_2$ about circle $I$.
Then we get four consecutively touching circles $O_7,O_2,O_3,O_6$ that all touches circles $O_1,O_4$.

Denote the curvature (reciprocal of radius) of circle $O_i$ by $k_i$.
From Descartes' theorem,
\begin{align}
& k_7=k_1+k_2+k_4+2 \sqrt{k_1 k_2+k_2 k_4+k_4 k_1} \\
& k_6=k_1+k_3+k_4+2 \sqrt{k_1 k_3+k_3 k_4+k_4 k_1} \\
& k_4=k_1+k_2+k_3-2 \sqrt{k_1 k_2+k_2 k_3+k_3 k_1}
\end{align}
Eliminating $k_1,k_4$, WolframAlpha gives
$$(k_2 - k_6) (k_3 - k_7) (3 k_2 - 3 k_3 + k_6 - k_7) = 0$$
So
$$\tag⋆
3 k_2 - 3 k_3 + k_6 - k_7=0$$
But WolframAlpha doesn't give step-by-step solution.
How to prove $(⋆)$?

Two circles $C_3,C_7$ have common tangent circles $O_1,O_2,O_4$. By Descartes' theorem
$$
k_{3,7}=k_1+k_2-k_4\pm2\sqrt{k_1 k_2-k_1 k_4-k_2 k_4}
$$
Adding,
$$\tag1
k_3+k_7=2k_1+2k_2-2k_4
$$
Similarly, two circles $C_2,C_6$ have common tangent circles $O_1,O_3,O_4$. By Descartes' theorem
$$
k_{2,6}=k_1+k_3-k_4\pm2\sqrt{k_1 k_3-k_1 k_4-k_3 k_4}
$$
Adding,
$$\tag2
k_2+k_6=2k_1+2k_3-2k_4
$$
$(1)-(2)$, we get $(⋆)$
$$k_7-k_6=3(k_2-k_3)$$
